# Intellij: Change project indent from 4 spaces to 2 spaces

Tags: intellij-idea

Currently, all of my project files are indented with 4 spaces. I want to change that to 2 spaces as my organization uses 2 as an standard, but can't find any answers.

Comment: Highlight one file project with the 4 spaces included.  Press Ctrl+F4 to bring the Find and Replace text box.  Copy and paste the file (without the spaces) to the Replace text box.  Then press Replace or Replace next :)

Comment: Similar question with an approved answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27926762/intellij-indents-4-spaces-when-i-have-configured-it-to-do-2-spaces-less

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Depending on your version of IDEA, it should be in your settings under:
`Editor > Code Style > (Specific language)`

**Edit: Example, in IDEA 2016:
[image]

If you don't see it there, I found mine by searching "indent" in the settings window.

Finally, for organization-wide code settings, I highly recommend [EditorConfig](http://editorconfig.org/). It's compatible with just about every IDE out there and lets you enforce code style settings without requiring everyone to manually change their settings to match. IDEA supports it out of the box, without a plugin.

Comment: Code style does not have specific language option or the amount of indentation.

Comment: Edited my answer to add a picture showing the options tree as well as the options you're looking for.

If yours doesn't look like this, then you'll need to tell us what version of IDEA you have.

Comment: Good to know about EditorConfig! Thanks @JamesTanner

Comment: @JamesTanner I would also note that Ctrl + Shift + A on Windows allows you to search for anything. If you search for indent, it will have the same effect as your statement about searching for indent in the Settings window.

Comment: @CacheStaheli, quite true. However, I find keyboard shortcuts provide for unreliable instructions, since IDEA includes no fewer than three different sets of them you can choose out of the box. (Varying by both operating system and which other IDE you would like to pretend you are using.)

Comment: the question was about "change project indent" not "IDE settings". for example, I can have 2 projects with 2 spaces indent and 4 spaces indent. downvote

Comment: You may have to also uncheck "Smart Indent" in the "Smart Keys" tab.

Comment: @AlexeySh. By default, IDEA stores settings on a per-project basis. So changing this setting changes it for that particular project, not the entire IDE.

Comment: This  applied changes to only that specific file. How to apply the changes to existing files in other folder of the project?

Answer (score 0):

Go to preferences ( for mac users ) or Settings ( Windows / Ubuntu )

Search for code style and select your language ( in my case its java ).

You can find at right side "Tabs and Indents" which i highlighted in below picture.

[image: Intellij Preferences]

You can set your tabs and indents according to your needs.

FYI. For those who cannot see my above screenshot, Please use the below link.

[IntelliJ Preferences](https://github.com/sujithramanathan/images/blob/main/intellij_preferences.png)