# Intellij: how to convert indents for all files

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I know how to convert indent for a single file. I go to edit -> convert indent -> space/tab.

But I want to do this for all files under a directory.

I try click on a directory and then go to edit -> convert indent, but the options are grayed out.

[image]

Comment: Did you try going in the Code Style settings - see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37754203/intellij-change-project-indent-from-4-spaces-to-2-spaces)

Comment: @forgetaboutme yes, I did that.

Comment: Have you run "Code | Reformat Code" on the directory after configuring code style?

Answer (score 9):

You can use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (Windows/Linux) or <kbd>⌥⌘</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (MAC OS X) and select the **Rearrange entries** option to reformat the code in the current file or reformat a module or directory.

You can also Right-click a module, file, or directory from the context menu and select **Reformat Code** and also select the **Rearrange entries** option.

This will convert the indents for all files/directories selected:

[image]

This works on most of the Jetbrains IDES (iDea, PyCharm, WebStorm, RubyMine, and so on.)

Comment: Reformatting/Rearranging code is not what the OP asked for. Changing the indents is just a minor fraction of what *Reformat code* does and is irrelevant to *Rearrange entries*. I'm also looking for something like this, in order just to change indents in a badly formatted codebase, without breaking the git history tracking completely.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no such dedicated option in IntelliJ, but you could just work around it using a "low-level" Replace All action.

- Open the **Edit → Find → Replace in Files...** dialog
- In case you want to convert spaces to tabs, you should

  - Enter      in the Find field (i.e. four spaces (or whatever number of spaces the project is currently indented with))
  - Press the **Regex** search modifier (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>)
  - Enter `\t` in the Replace field
  - ***NB***: In case you have valid strings with 4+ spaces in them, they will get replaced too. In most use cases, however, this is not happening.
- In case you want to convert tabs to spaces, you should do the same as above, but swap the Find and Replace field contents

  - ***NB***: Again, if you have valid strings with tabs in them, they will get replaced too. I haven't had this use case, because I've only needed to convert in the opposite direction.
- You will probably also want to set a **File mask** in order not to replace spaces in code-irrelevant files