# Intellij: problem with setting indent for TypeScript

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, indentation, text-styling

I'm trying to set indent for TypeScript in Intellij Idea Ultimate.
I'm doing this like others described in previous questions eg. [question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37754203/intellij-change-project-indent-from-4-spaces-to-2-spaces), [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044472/how-to-correct-indentation-in-intellij).
It's not working in my case.

Indent should be 4, it's set to 4, in preview it looks good, but there is no changes in editor after closing settings window by `Apply` and `Ok` and formatting code by shortcut `Ctrl + Alt + L`

Could you tell me what i'm doing incorrect ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check that your file is not already indented with 2 (or another number) spaces. As Intelliji/Webstorm always favor current indentation. If that is your case, you can fix that by manually indenting your file to 4 spaces, once.

One faster way to do it, is to remove all indentation, by doing shift-tab multiple times, on the whole file, then doing ctrl+alt+L.

Also check indentation settings in your tslint.json or eslint.json file if you have one.

Comment: I tried your ideas, but any of them worked. I set in `tslint.json` indent options

`"indent": {   "options": [   "spaces", 4  ]  }`
but it don't work too. I found that intellij has `.editorconfig` file which has only read access, and there is option `indent_size = 2` which overrides all my settings. Probably it can be reason. How to change it ?

Comment: @StreamGuy I find it strange that you need to change files in `.idea/` folder to make it work. You probably can replace that readonly file by replacing it with a modified version of yours (overwrite file instead of modifying).